# ERROR: “/app/etc/” must exist for proper tool work in magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, install, patches, shell

I am trying to install the newly release security patch for magento 1.8 in my distant server when I get this error
[image]

I tried to edit CURRENT_DIR in the sh file with pwd value and I always get the same error.

Is there a way to be fixed

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry for stupid question: is that your magento root folder?

Answer (score 1):

Magento patches need to be run from you the root of your web folder. For example if your website is located at

```
/var/www/domain.com/magentoroot/
```

You would run the patch from

```
sh /var/www/domain.com/magentoroot/name_of_patch.sh
```

You will get verification on the command line of what the patch is doing. I would redown load the patch and apply as you have stated you modified it already.

Comment: HTTP doc root or Magento root? I thought it had to be run in the directory where you can see app/ as it looks for app/etc/applied.patches.list from the current directory.

Comment: I don't get the difference, anyway the patch is located in /www/name_of_patch.sh and the value of pwd when I open putty is /home.5/my_domain_name

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set the write permission to the folder `app/etc` under the Magento root folder. The patch will create a file called `applied.patches.list` to store the patches applied details.

Comment: Do you really suggests people to make app/etc to have write permission?

Comment: When we do install and apply the patches this is necessary. After these are done you can remove this permission.